# Upload video in Node/Express

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload, uppy

Best way to handle video uploads in Node/Express, storage in AWS S3 Bucket?

Preferably with some beginner-friendly docs.

Looked at Uppy but can’t for the world figure out how it works server side.